# Twitterizer throwing an exception: Unexpected token when deserializing object: Integer

Tags: c#, json, exception, twitter, twitterizer

I'm encountering a JSON (de)serialization exception when using [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/)'s [`LookUp`](http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/) method. The exception states:

> Unexpected token when deserializing object: Integer

Here is roughly what my code looks like:

```
// Populates the lookup options, requests the user details and processes the results
private void LookUpFollowersWithoutDetail(List<Follower> followersWithoutDetail)
{
    LookupUsersOptions lookupOptions = new LookupUsersOptions();

    for (int index = 0; index < followersWithoutDetail.Count && index < 100; index++)
    {
        lookupOptions.UserIds.Add(followersWithoutDetail[index].UserId);
    }

    RequestResult result = GetUserDetails(lookupOptions);
    // process the results
}
```

The method that gets the user details looks like this:

```
// Performs the lookup and saves the users to the database
private RequestResult GetUserDetails(LookupUsersOptions lookupOptions)
{
    try
    {
        // Look up the followers
        TwitterResponse<TwitterUserCollection> userLookupResponse = 
            TwitterUser.Lookup(_tokens, lookupOptions); // <-- Throws Exception
        if (userLookupResponse.Result == RequestResult.Success)
        {
            SaveUserDetails(userLookupResponse);
        }
        return userLookupResponse.Result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in GetUserDetails: " + e.Message);
    }
    return RequestResult.Unknown;
}
```

I don't do anything fancy, I just put a bunch of integers (User Id's of the followers) in the lookup options and then I call the lookup method with those options. Most of the time the method works fine, but every once in a while I get the exception mentioned in the beginning of this post. Has anybody encountered a similar issue with Twitterizer and have they figured out a solution?

**Update (for Ricky):**

Here is the stack trace:

> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueProperty(JsonReader reader, JsonProperty property, Object target, Boolean gottenCurrentValue, Object currentValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonReader reader, Object target)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueProperty(JsonReader reader, JsonProperty property, Object target, Boolean gottenCurrentValue, Object currentValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonReader reader, Object target)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IWrappedCollection wrappedList, JsonReader reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract contract)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(IList l, Boolean isTemporaryListReference)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CollectionUtils.CreateAndPopulateList(Type listType, Action`2 populateList)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateList(JsonReader reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract contract)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String reference)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
>      at Twitterizer.Core.SerializationHelper`1.Deserialize(Byte[] webResponseData, DeserializationHandler deserializationHandler)
>      at Twitterizer.Core.TwitterCommand`1.ExecuteCommand()
>      at Twitterizer.Core.CommandPerformer.PerformAction[T](ICommand`1 command)
>      at Twitterizer.TwitterUser.Lookup(OAuthTokens tokens, LookupUsersOptions options)
>      at OBFUSCATED.System.OBFUSCATED.GetUserDetails(LookupUsersOptions lookupOptions) in C:\Users\user\Path\To\MyClass.cs:line 306

Here is the list of User Id's that were supplied when this exception occurred:

```
-       lookupOptions.UserIds   Count = 100 Twitterizer.TwitterIdCollection
        [0] 39026441    decimal
        [1] 360825202   decimal
        [2] 377779483   decimal
        [3] 77599652    decimal
        [4] 199504556   decimal
        [5] 15290529    decimal
        [6] 15293368    decimal
        [7] 15295132    decimal
        [8] 15295838    decimal
        [9] 15300610    decimal
        [10]    15307479    decimal
        [11]    15314695    decimal
        [12]    15315646    decimal
        [13]    15316087    decimal
        [14]    15322893    decimal
        [15]    15324552    decimal
        [16]    15325815    decimal
        [17]    15330982    decimal
        [18]    15332031    decimal
        [19]    15332318    decimal
        [20]    15336542    decimal
        [21]    15338843    decimal
        [22]    15340130    decimal
        [23]    15341396    decimal
        [24]    15341681    decimal
        [25]    15342905    decimal
        [26]    15343278    decimal
        [27]    15351598    decimal
        [28]    15358123    decimal
        [29]    15361196    decimal
        [30]    15361723    decimal
        [31]    15363684    decimal
        [32]    15365834    decimal
        [33]    15366588    decimal
        [34]    15375866    decimal
        [35]    15377256    decimal
        [36]    15384679    decimal
        [37]    15384994    decimal
        [38]    15388036    decimal
        [39]    15388874    decimal
        [40]    15390556    decimal
        [41]    15397486    decimal
        [42]    15398320    decimal
        [43]    15401318    decimal
        [44]    15421131    decimal
        [45]    15421937    decimal
        [46]    15422192    decimal
        [47]    15433173    decimal
        [48]    15433807    decimal
        [49]    15435566    decimal
        [50]    15447574    decimal
        [51]    15448831    decimal
        [52]    15449755    decimal
        [53]    15450751    decimal
        [54]    15452924    decimal
        [55]    15456465    decimal
        [56]    15456590    decimal
        [57]    15458653    decimal
        [58]    15458901    decimal
        [59]    15461998    decimal
        [60]    15465107    decimal
        [61]    15467755    decimal
        [62]    15468099    decimal
        [63]    15470126    decimal
        [64]    15475251    decimal
        [65]    15475461    decimal
        [66]    15478303    decimal
        [67]    15479254    decimal
        [68]    15479572    decimal
        [69]    15479736    decimal
        [70]    15484821    decimal
        [71]    15487227    decimal
        [72]    15487287    decimal
        [73]    15489577    decimal
        [74]    15490132    decimal
        [75]    15501961    decimal
        [76]    15503943    decimal
        [77]    15505543    decimal
        [78]    15510316    decimal
        [79]    15515724    decimal
        [80]    15523378    decimal
        [81]    15526558    decimal
        [82]    15529204    decimal
        [83]    15538443    decimal
        [84]    15554417    decimal
        [85]    15564955    decimal
        [86]    15569189    decimal
        [87]    15575242    decimal
        [88]    15575635    decimal
        [89]    15578111    decimal
        [90]    15580710    decimal
        [91]    15585660    decimal
        [92]    15589332    decimal
        [93]    15594166    decimal
        [94]    15597341    decimal
        [95]    15603662    decimal
        [96]    15608792    decimal
        [97]    15618128    decimal
        [98]    15620785    decimal
        [99]    15620915    decimal
+       Raw View
```

Comment: 2 questions: Can you supply a stack trace and would it be possible to supply the user ids that you're looking up?

It looks like something is failing to parse correctly, which means Twitter has change some format in a very small way and I'll need to tweak the library to match.

Comment: Ricky Smith, I'm going to supply those in a little bit. I'll update the question ASAP.

Comment: @Ricky ...AND DONE: see the update for stack trace and user IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into this, I've determined Twitter didn't change anything. This appears to be a real live bug having to do with parsing geo location data.

JSON.NET (the library Twitterizer uses to deserialize json data) reads a coordinate value as a long, but Twitterizer is casting it as a double.

Two lines of code later and the bug is fixed.

If you would like to apply the patch yourself, the fix is in Twitterizer2\Methods\Geo\Coordinate.cs

Line 119 becomes:

```cs
result[itemIndex].Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value);
```

Line 123 becomes:

```cs
result[itemIndex].Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm probably going to pull the latest version of Twitterizer and make the changes since this bug is causing me to miss a lot of data.

Comment: Update: I just built the library with the above-mentioned modifications and it works like a charm!!!

Comment: I just need to understand, i did not update twitterizer nor newtonsoft json serializer, but all of a sudden it crashed on my live site, if twitter didnt change anything, how could it crash just like that? did the coordinates get longer all in one day? or is it something that happened because of one tweet that messed up the pile?

Comment: @Ayyash I don't know if your question is in context with the overall question, but it could be that Twitter changed some data or that you've run into data that I've never encountered during testing and Twitterizer can't handle it. Please post your issue on our forums or as its own question on SO with stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: no your answer fixed my problem, but i was commenting on the first line of the answer: "After looking into this, I've determined Twitter didn't change anything." and it made me wonder, if no one changed anything how could it have crashed all of a sudden? but you're right it maybe purely circumstantial